# How to convert a string (number representation) to an arbitrary base using custom alphabet?

Tags: algorithms, python, base-conversion

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way (without recursion) to convert a string (number representation) from one arbitrary base to another using custom alphabet. But I cannot think of a very fast efficient method (byte shift?) to do it:

```python
def convert_base(target, base_from, base_to):
  alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  base_to_alphabet_slice = alphabet[:base_to]
  base_from_alphabet_slice = alphabet[:base_from]
  result = ''
  for char in target:
    result += ...
  return result

# Expected results:
print(convert_base('E', 16, 2)) 
# Output: '1110'

print(convert_base('1110', 2, 16))
# Output: 'E'

print(convert_base('E', 16, 10))
# Output: '14'
```

Can someone suggest a good method for this?

Comment: Base conversion isn't trivial when no base is an integral multiple of the other. Why would *using custom alphabet* change that?

Comment: @greybeard sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. I need the custom alphabet so I can define a custom number system, not for the purpose of simplifying the implementation of the algorithm. For example, we use the alphabet `0123456789ABCDEF` to convert numbers from base10 to base16 and back. I extended the alphabet just so I can convert larger bases.

Comment: [Base conversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion) is one wrought-out topic. If interested in not-so-basic ideas, follow the link in [Yuval Filmus' answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/21799).